# How do I get a list of the values of matching attributes using xmllint and xpath?

Tags: shell, xml, xmllint

I'm trying to use xmllint to parse names of Solr cores from the configuration file.
This works:

`xmllint --xpath /solr/cores/core/@name solr.xml |grep -Po '(?<=name=")[a-z-]+(?=")'`

And it returns something like:

```
core-a
core-b
...
```

Which is exactly what I want, but I would like to eliminate grep. It seems like one should be able to do this with just xpath. Without grep, the output looks like:

```
name="core-a" name="core-b" ...
```

Wrapping the expressions in `string()` reduces the multiple output to just the first (ie `core-a` and that's it), which is not useful. How can I apply the `string` function on each result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, `xmllint` is rather limited. But you can use [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) with its `sel` command for what you want to do. See `xmlstarlet sel --help` for usage and an example. With your example, it would be:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m /solr/cores/core/@name -v . -n solr.xml
```